# Why do toolbars not show up?

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocumentreader

Can someone please tell me why the zoom and search controls do not show up?

Here is the code:

```
<FlowDocumentReader x:Name="myDocumenReader" Height="269.4">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Section Foreground="Yellow" Background="Black">
             <Paragraph FontSize="20">
                  Here are some fun facts about the WPF Documents API!
             </Paragraph>
        </Section>
        <!--<List />
        <Paragraph />-->
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Short answer - Because `FlowDocumentReader` doesn't have one defined in its template.

Comment: I am sorry but there is no way to answer this question.  You give no context, no code and no explanation.

Comment: @RohitVats: "*FlowDocumentReader doesn't have one defined in its template*". According to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader?view=netframework-4.8): "*Tool Bar - The default toolbar is docked underneath the content area. It hosts controls for searching content, navigating pages, selecting a viewing mode, and changing the zoom level.*"

Answer (score 1):

I realized in the Document Outline I just needed to expand the width and height of the window and the FlowDocumentReader.
The controls were there the whole time.

Comment: Thanks for posting the explanation. I had the same problem following [this exercise from the WPF 4.5 Unleashed](https://books.google.com/books?id=ubgRAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA334&lpg=PA334) which shows exactly the same problem (which seems a bug by the way).